# expected ',' or ';' before 'do' Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c++

Начинаю компилировать и выходит ошибка кода, вот:      (недоделал пока)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void check_pass (string password)

{
       string people_pass="Samsung";

       if(password==people_pass)
       {
           cout<<" Äîñòóï ðàçðåø¸í."<<endl;
           float prohodka=1;
       }
       else
       {
           cout<<"Äîñòóï çàïðåù¸í."<<endl;
           float prohodka=0;
       }


}


int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
       setlocale(0,"");

       float prohodka = 0

       do {
       string user_pass;
       cout<<"Ââåäèòå ïàðîëü : ";
       getline(cin,user_pass);
       check_pass(user_pass);   
          }
       while(prohodka == 0);




       system("pause");
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли ";" перед do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пропущена `;`. Должно быть так:

```
float prohodka = 0;
```

Comment: Facepalm, Блин, как так-то? Спасибо, не заметил)

Comment: А еще `#include <string>` отсутствует...

Comment: Хм... он и так принимает, но кстати, а чем отличается <string> от <string.h>?

Comment: @Melant, по сути ничем, только способ найти этот заголовок.

Comment: @Melant, если .h - то скорее всего это библиотека пришла с языка Си, а если без, то С++. Но это как правило.

Comment: @MrBin это не совсем так- <string.h>  выдает неявно доступные имена,